# What are the GEM_DEP_FILES entries in rubygems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have been trying to learn more about the rubygems system in ruby. One curious constant I have encountered is GEM_DEP_FILES. The ruby-doc.org page for Module: Gem has nothing to say about this value other than its name. Here is what I get in irb:

```
irb(main):002:0> Gem::GEM_DEP_FILES
=> ["gem.deps.rb", "Gemfile", "Isolate"]
```

Now "Gemfile" is the dependency mechanism we all know and love. I think; At least it is the same name.

My question is what about the others?

A wild guess is that "gem.deps.rb" is some old, obsolete predecessor to "Gemfile"? Maybe?

I have no clue at all about the entry called "Isolate".

I have looked with no success. Can anyone shed any light about these obscure entries?

In case it matters:

```
20 mysh>ruby --version
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]
21 mysh>gem --version
2.5.2
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem.html

I am working to add a utility command to my mysh program that will display pertinent gem related info, so any info, advice, or guidance would be most welcome.

Comment: Perhaps `gem help gem_dependencies` will shed some light?

Comment: A good source of info for sure. I was too focused on API level docs that I missed application level docs. Still, I was hoping somebody could shed light on the specific names gems.deps.rb and Isolate.

Comment: https://github.com/jbarnette/isolate may be the origin of `Isolate`?